# How to open the red-button menu on Visual Studio (2008) with the keyboard?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcut

When you type something and there's some problem you get a tiny red rectangle at the end of the symbol/word that has the problem and when you hover the mouse over it, you get a button and when you press the button you get a list of possible actions to fix the problem, including adding using statements or refactoring.

Is there a way to open that menu with the keyboard so I don't have to reach my mouse?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f10</kbd> works there is an alternate shortcut i find easier to type:

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>

Answer (score 11):

I believe <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> also works...that's what I've been using all these years...fewer keystrokes

Comment: amazing... never thought of finding the shortcut for that... sure a huge time saver!

Comment: thanks for the kbd formatting bdukes...didn't realize that was available...cool.

Answer (score 3):

Found it, in the tooltip: <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

It is <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>

Here are a list of the keyboard shortcuts

[Visual Basic](http://www.microsoft.com/downloadS/details.aspx?familyid=255B8CF1-F6BD-4B55-BB42-DD1A69315833&displaylang=en)

[C#](http://www.microsoft.com/downloadS/details.aspx?FamilyID=e5f902a8-5bb5-4cc6-907e-472809749973&displaylang=en)